# Pedometer not working, iPhone 5 and also not working on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift

I am also using same code in WatchKit extension but I am getting same error and could not figure out where is problem , I also check the code in iPhone 5, 5s , Apple Watch

```
    self.manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1
    let fromDateString = "2017-09-1"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    let fromDate = dateFormatter.date(from: fromDateString)



    if(CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable()){

        let mainQ = OperationQueue.main

        self.activityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: mainQ, withHandler: { (data: CMMotionActivity!) -> Void in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if(data.stationary == true){
                    self.activityState.text = "Stationary"
                } else if (data.walking == true){
                    self.activityState.text = "Walking"
                } else if (data.running == true){
                    self.activityState.text = "Running"
                } else if (data.automotive == true){
                    self.activityState.text = "Automotive"
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

////////////// Plz look into it where I m doing wrong//////////

```
    if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()) {

        self.pedoMeter.queryPedometerData(from: fromDate!, to: Date.init()) { (data : CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if(error == nil){
                    self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                }
            })
        }
    }

    let todya = Date.init()
    self.pedoMeter.startUpdates(from: todya) { (data: CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
```

/***** I get this error every time

Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (CMErrorDomain error 104.)")

*/

```
            if(error == nil){
                self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is Apple's. `isStepCountingAvailable` should have returned `false`, as these devices have no pedometer capabilities.